# Disable white space on key press in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, keypress

I am beginner in WinForms so i would like to learn that,

How can i disable white space keypress in textbox?

```
private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // MyTextBox.Text ...?
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should never use a keypressevent to disable keys. Its unsafe (f.e: "ctrl + c"). Use the Textchangedevent instead

Comment: @Pengu How do you define 'unsafe'?  Are you talking about the fact that it doesn't correctly handle forbidding a paste operation from putting spaces in the textbox?

Comment: @Corey Yes, thats what i mean. But its not only that - there are also other possibilities like "ALT + Code", and i can imagine that there a some more ways to put in text without the keypressevent recognise it.

Comment: Set e.Handled to true.  Do note that this doesn't actually stop the user from putting spaces in text box, he can use Paste.  Use the Validating event instead.

Answer (score 8):

that's what you want, disallows all spaces

```
    private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {              
         e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
 private void txt_keyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) \
    { 
         if ((sender as TextBox).SelectionStart == 0)
          e.Handled = (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space);
     else
          e.Handled = false; 
    }
```

Comment: You can just return e.Handled = true;

Comment: This checks only the first key press